# How to determine the end of string in VFP 9?

Tags: string, visual-foxpro

In some programming languages, such as C for example, the end of string may be marked as a separate null terminator symbol.

How do I determine if the current symbol is the end of string?

Currently I use some string functions' calls, but I guess it may be performed easier.

```
*the string's end
IF ISBLANK(SUBSTR(str, pos, 1) == .T.  AND CHR(32) != SUBSTR(str, pos,  1)
    RETURN .T.
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VFP strings are not ASCIIZ strings as in C. A VFP string can contain any ASCII character including character 0 - chr(0)- which is a string termination character in C style languages.
Normally the end of the string in VFP is the same as its length. But, although it is not clear from your question, sometimes you get a string from a C source (ie: a win32 call) where multiple string values are separated by chr(0) values. You can easily parse such a string into multiple string with a code like alines(). ie:

```
? ALines(laLines, "hello"+Chr(0)+"there",1+4,Chr(0)) && prints 2
display memory like laLines && shows two string values
```

Also you could use many string function like at(), occurs(), asc() ... to locate, count ... that character.

Comment: Initially the goal was to store a text (probably huge) from the clipboard using _cliptext and do some per string processing. So ALINES( ) function was the answer! It simplifies access to the separate line.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to worry about C-style string termination in VFP.

Assuming you don't care what the last character is then from your example:

```
return (pos = len(str))
```

If you want to ignore spaces:

```
return (pos = len(alltrim(str))
```

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't think about how the string ends in VFP until working with a long text in a Character variable.